# preg_replace: How to not remove the whole part?

Tags: php, preg-replace

I got this string:

```
$string = "hello123hello237ihello523";
```

I want to search for an "o" followed by a number. Then I want to remove only the "o".

I've been trying:

```
preg_replace("/kl[0-9]/", "", $string);
```

The problem is that is removes the number as well. I only want to remove the "o". Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

use positive lookahead:

```
echo preg_replace("/o(?=[0-9])/", "", $string);
```

For more information: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

One other option is:

```
echo preg_replace("/o([0-9])/", "\\1", $string);
```

This will replace the o[number] with [number]

Comment: According to the docs, `$1` is preferable to `\\1` since PHP 4.0.4.

Comment: @cbuckley, you're correct, but "preferable" doesn't mean that \\1 is deprecated. Since most of the other languages use the \\1 syntax, I prefer to stick with it :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use back references:

```
echo preg_replace('/o([0-9])/', '$1', $string);
```

See [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) for information on referencing subpatterns.